# ABAP Eclipse Oxygen: Where Used Queries Don't Work

Tags: abap, abap-adt

I'm trying to perform a Where Used Query for a method of a class.  It doesn't work.  First, the query runs for minutes.  Then finally it responds with an error that Where-used is not supported "for this object", which doesn't make sense for a class method. Has anybody seen this before? Your help fixing this issue will be appreciated!  FYI, I'm using Eclipse Oxygen with latest ADT installed.

Error Message

Comment: Never seen that. Unexpected behavior mostly results from out-of-date ADT versions, but you say you have the latest. However, this is definitely something for SAP's support, not for StackOverflow!

Comment: Thanks Florian. I've taken your advice and submitted an OSS Message.  Keeping my fingers crossed. I need Where-Used queries to work! For now, I have to peform them in SE24.

Comment: For me it works brilliantly. Your Oxygen installation more than likely is corrupted. Try to reinstall it.